# How to combine/merge multiple DataFrameGroupBy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy>` objects and would like to combine them by a key?  How would I do that?. Having 'as_index=False' does not work(it used to work before) I tried the following

```
result = pd.merge(groupobject_a, groupobject_b, on='important_key', how='inner')
```

But I am getting error below

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
```

Here is my minimal code how I created my groupby objects

```
import pandas as pd
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv("here is my csv")
groupobject_a= my_dataframe[(my_dataframe['colA'] > 0) & (my_dataframe['colB'] < 15) & (my_dataframe['colC'].notnull())].groupby(['important_key'], as_index=False)
groupobject_b= my_dataframe[(my_dataframe['colA'] > 25) & (my_dataframe['colB'] < 65) & (my_dataframe['colC'].notnull())].groupby(['important_key'], as_index=False)
```

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: groupby object can not merge , try just filter then merge , it should work '

Comment: You can have a `df` from `groupby` object with `pd.DataFrame({groupbyobject_a.size()}).reset_index()`. Then you can merge the dataframes.

Comment: @Wen - can you post a snippet how to do it?@sacul updated